# Should I test front-end and back-end separately

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

So I have a full stack MERN app, and I want to add tests to it to ease further development. I tried to find some answers but didn't come across anything useful.

My question is: Is it better to have 2 separate scripts like `test-backend` and `test-frontend` which test their respective areas, or is it better to have 1 unified script which does both? For example, let's say you're working on the back end and don't want to waste time testing the front end, wouldn't it be advantageous to have the tests separated?

PS: I'm using JEST for my tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you organize your frontend and backend code in different folders. Frontend and backend code should have their own tests. This makes it easier to work on tests.

Also, separating tests makes it easier to run them separately. e.g. just run frontend tests, or backend tests. Typically test runners accept a path to run tests in that path. I would suggest separating tests for different modules of backend or frontend, too.

example:

- frontend/

  - tests/

    - user/
    - shop/
- backend

  - tests

    - user/
    - shop/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you generally unit test frontend and backend separately.

But you can also write e2e tests that test the whole app.